# populating a Java thrift object from another Java thrift object

Tags: java, thrift

I have 2 different thrift objects generated in java called ThriftObject1 and ThriftObject2 with same fields and types some thing like this.

```
ThriftObjectJava1 - field1, field2

ThriftObjectJava1 - field1, field2
```

The problem thrift object has handful of fields, so is there any method defined to populate object of type1 to thrift object type 2 rather that copying field by field?

Answer (score 1):

You can clone the object using [`Object.clone()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29). For this your class should implement [`Cloneable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Cloneable.html).

So, if `ThriftObjectJava1` implements cloneable, `object1 = object2.clone()` will give you a shallow copy. It is called a shallow copy because clone

> initializes all its fields with exactly the contents of the
>   corresponding fields of this object, as if by assignment; the contents
>   of the fields are not themselves cloned. Thus, this method performs a
>   "shallow copy" of this object, not a "deep copy" operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an object mapping library like [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net) and create a mapping between `ThriftObjectJava1` and `ThriftObjectJava2`. This should allow you to very quickly "convert" from one object to another.